# Creating classes for shop's products

Tags: java, hierarchy

Let's say a there is a shop that sells two kinds of products, computer components and peripherals. Components category includes:

- Mobo - gpu type(amd/intel), num. of SATA ports(4/6/8) ...
- CPU - Frequency(3, 3.6, 4 GHz), num. of cores(2/4/6/8), onboard graphics(yes or no)...
- RAM - type(DDR2, DDR3, DDR4), memory (2/4/8 GB), frequenct (1600, 2666, 4600 MHz)
- GPU - chipset(AMD/nVidia), memory(2/4/6 GB)
- Storage - type(HDD/SSD), dimensions(1.8, 2.5, 3.5 inch), capacity(256/500/...)
- Monitor - type(LCD/LED), dimensions, resolution, ports(Display Port/HDMI/DVI
- Mouse - technology(laser/optical), connectivity(wireless or wired)
- Keyboard - Connectivity(wireless or wired)
- Printer - technology(laser/inkjet), kind of printing(black and white or coloured)

All products though have some common features like : model, year, manufacturer and price.

The kind of product matters because if a product is a component, the client get 25% discount and if it is a peripheral the client gets 10% discount, so that is important for what i need to implement afterwards.

Basically, my question is: How to organise all these into classes? 
I guess i need to create a class called Product(Top of the hierarchy) with instance variables: model, year, manufacturer, price. 
Then a Mobo class with instaces: gpu type, num. of SATA ports...
a CPU class with instance variables: Frequency, num of cores .... etc. Should i create two more classes, Components and Peripherals? What instance variables will they include?

Comment: 1. Favor [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) 2. I would consider implementing simple methods like `isComponent()` and `isPeripheral()` and just calling them to determine what kind of discount.  The other idea is `getDiscount()` and let any product calculate its own discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to express this kind of thing in code, and it is difficult for other people to know what will be best for you.

I recommend that you use an object modeling notation (like UML) to work out for yourself the most appropriate way to model your data; i.e. the model that is going to be the best fit for your requirements.  In UML (for example) you can model:

- classes and subclasses
- containment relationships between classes
- other relationships between class (one to one, one to many, many to many)

and if you want to go that far

- attributes of classes
- method signatures
- method semantics (in OCL)
- interactions
- etcetera

In the first instance, I'd recommend using a whiteboard ... and a mobile phone to capture the diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you have to create a package so you can stay organized.

You should create a class for each type of product. But you might also need some interfaces here and there. Remember also that classes are just blueprints for objects, therefore classes are nothing at all without objects.